# Enable IPSec on Firewall

Tags: firewall, ipsec

I am using ProfitBrick for my Cloud infra. 
However, if I enable their firewall, IPsec does not pass through.
The ports opened on firewall are:

```
TCP 53
TCP 51
TCP 4500
TCP 500
UDP 4500
UDP 500
```

Does anybody know if I have to open other ports?

Comment: Have you double checked the ports are open from an external side, If not then use a service such as http://ping.eu/port-chk/

Comment: You have to pass ESP and AH as well. Contact ProfitBricks as their [firewall does not seem capable of this](https://www.profitbricks.com/help/Firewall).